# Can we run Linux guest OS in Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer, lab

I've been using VirtualBox, and GNS3 for a while and recently I found out about Cisco Packet Tracer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_Tracer

I've downloaded it and it seems like this tool is focusing more into Cisco Networking.

The good things about this tool is I can run a lot of guests (pcs, routers, switches) and memory utilization is still very low. Not like GNS3 & VirtualBox.

My question is, can I run actual Linux OS in this packet tracer as I can run it on VirtualBox and GNS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packet tracer is fairly limited. It is designed to let someone practice for the CCNA exams. It doesn't include all the IOS features, only a subset of commands that are useful for CCNA-level exercises.

Packet Tracer is not going to give you what you seem to want.

Answer (score 4):

Packet tracer is a simulator unlike GNS3 which is an emulator. so you cant run linux guest os in packet tracer

Answer (score 2):

You should look into Cisco VIRL. Much more options and seems to be Cisco’s roadmap for emulation instead of packet tracer.